# Prob. 16, Sec. 2.3, in Herstein's TOPICS IN ALGEBRA, 2nd ed: A finite set closed under an associative product with only one of the cancellation laws

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, examples-counterexamples, binary-operations

Here is Prob. 14, Sec. 2.3, in the book *Topics in Algebra* by I.N. Herstein, 2nd edition:

> Suppose a *finite* set $G$ is closed under an associative product and that both cancellation laws hold in $G$. Prove that $G$ must be a group.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636634/prob-14-sec-2-3-in-hersteins-topics-in-algebra-2nd-ed-a-finite-set-with-a) is a Mathematics Stack Exchange post on this problem.

And, here is Prob. 16, Sec. 2.3, in the book *Topics in Algebra* by I.N. Herstein, 2nd edition:

> In Problem 14 show by an example that if one just assumed one of the cancellation laws, then the conclusion need not hold.

My Attempt:

> Let 
>   $$ G = \{ \, 1, -1 \, \}. $$
>   And for any $a, b \in G$, let $a * b$ be defined as
>   $$ a*b \colon= a \, \lvert b \rvert. $$
>   Thus we have $$ 1 * 1 = 1 = 1 * (-1), \qquad (-1)*1 = -1 = (-1) * (-1). $$
>
> We note that in this set $G$ with this binary operation $*$, the *left* cancellation law does not hold, for although we have $$ 1 * 1 = 1 = 1 * (-1), $$
>   it is not true that $$ 1 = -1.$$
>
> However, the *right* cancellation law does indeed hold in $G$, for if $a$, $b$, and $c$ are any elements in $G$ and if $$ a * c = b * c, $$
>   then we have 
>   $$ a \, \lvert c \rvert = b \, \lvert c \rvert, $$
>   and since $c \neq 0$, therefore we must have 
>   $$ a = b. $$
>
> Thus in our set $G$ with this particular binary operation $*$, the right cancellation law holds but the left cancellation law does not.
>
> Moreover, for any elements $a$, $b$, and $c$ in $G$, we obtain
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> (a * b) * c &= \big(a \, \lvert b \rvert \big) * c \\
> &= \big(a \, \lvert b \rvert \big) \, \lvert c \rvert \\
> &= a \, \lvert b c \rvert \\
> &= a \, \big\lvert b \, \lvert c \rvert \, \big\rvert \\
> &= a \, \big\lvert \, b * c  \, \big\rvert \\
> &= a * ( b * c).
> \end{align}
> $$
>   This shows that $*$ is an *associative* binary operation on $G$.
>
> Thus $G$ is a finite set with an associative binary operation $*$ such that only *one* of the two cancellation laws holds in $G$.
>
> Finally, we note that this set $G$ with this particular binary operation $*$ is *not* a group, because $G$ contains no identity element.
>
> In order to see that $G$ with respect to $*$ contains no identity element, we note that as $$ 1 * (-1) \neq -1, $$ so $1$ cannot be an identity element (more precisely a *left* identity element) of $G$, and as $$ (-1) * 1  \neq 1, $$ so $-1$ cannot be an identity element (more precisely, a left identity element) of $G$.
>
> On the other hand, either of $1$ and $-1$ can serve as a *right* identity element in $G$, because for any element $a \in G$, we have
>   $$ a * (\pm 1) = a \, \lvert \pm 1 \rvert = a (1) = a. $$
>
> However, in a group a right identity element is also a left identity element, and there is a unique such element. See Lemma 2.3.1 a. in Herstein. And, also refer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2532072/problems-12-13-from-hersteins-book) Mathematics Stack Exchange post.

Is this example good enough? If so, then is my presentation clear enough too? Or, are there any issues?

> Now let us consider this same set $G$, namely, $$ G = \{ \, 1, -1 \, \}, $$
>   but now let $*$ be the binary operation on $G$ defined as follows: For any elements $a$ and $b$ of $G$, let us define $a ~ b$ as 
>   $$ a*b \colon= \lvert a \rvert \, b. $$
>   Then we have
>   $$ 1 * 1 = 1 = (-1) * 1, \qquad 1 * (-1) = -1 = (-1) * (-1).  $$
>   In this case, the *left* cancellation law holds in $G$, for if $a, b, c \in G$ and if $$ a * b = a * c, $$ then $$ \lvert a \rvert \, b = \lvert a \rvert \, c, $$ and as $a \neq 0$, so we must have $b = c$, but the *right* does not hold in $G$, for we have 
>   $$ 1 * 1 = (-1) * 1, $$ but $1 \neq -1$. And, this binary operation $*$ on $G$ is of course associative, for if $a, b, c \in G$, then we obtain 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> a * ( b * c ) &= a * \big( \lvert b \rvert \, c \big) \\
> &= \lvert a \rvert \, \big( \lvert b \rvert \, c \big) \\
> &= \lvert a \rvert \, \lvert b \rvert \, c \\
> &= \lvert a b \rvert \, c \\
> &= \big\lvert a \, \lvert b \rvert \big\rvert \, c \\
> &= \big\lvert a * b \big\rvert \, c \\
> &= (a * b) *c.
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> Thus again we have the finite set $G$ with an associative binary operation such that only one of the two cancellation laws holds in $G$.
>
> Finally, we note that this set $G$ with this particular binary operation $*$ is again not a group. The element $1$ of $G$ cannot serve as an identity element (from the right) because $(-1) * 1 \neq -1$, and $-1$ cannot serve as an identity element (again from the right) because $1 * (-1) \neq 1$, although either of $1$ and $-1$ can serve as an identity element from the left, because for any element $a \in G$ have $$ (\pm 1 ) * a = \lvert \pm 1 \rvert \, a = 1 \cdot a = a. $$

Is this example OK? Or, are there problems?

Any other examples of this kind please?

Comment: You have a typo:  you say $b=c$ when you actually mean $a=b$.  But I think the proof is otherwise both correct and well written.

Comment: @RobertShore I've corrected that typo. Thank you for reviewing my post. I've just seen your profile. I too want to pursue a law degree, or at least learn the core law subjects.

Comment: This is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I am reading "Topics in Algebra 2nd Edition" by I. N. Herstein.
This problem is Problem 16 on p.36.
I solved this problem as follows:

> Let $G=\{a,b\}$.
> Let $x\cdot a=a$ for any $x\in G$.
> Let $x\cdot b=b$ for any $x\in G$.
>
> Let $x,y\in G$.
> $(x\cdot y)\cdot a=a$.
> $x\cdot(y\cdot a)=x\cdot a=a$.
>
> $(x\cdot y)\cdot b=b$.
> $x\cdot(y\cdot b)=x\cdot b=b$.
>
> So, the associativity law holds in $G$.
>
> $a\cdot a=a\neq b=a\cdot b$.
> $b\cdot a=a\neq b=b\cdot b$.
> So, the left cancellation law holds in $G$.
>
> Since $a\cdot b=b$, $b$ is not an identity element.
> Since $b\cdot a=a$, $a$ is not an identity element.
> So, $G$ is not a group.